# Web2py AJAX autofilling of form

Tags: python, web2py, autofill

i've a from an i want to fill it automatically based on information from a data base and filled fields :

in db_wizard.py

```
db.define_table('sender',
  Field('name'), # e.g. Daniel
  Field('email'),# e.g. daniel@daniel.com
  Field('opening'), # e.g. Dear Daniel
  ...)           

db.define_table('receiver',
  Field('name'),  # e.g. John
  Field('email'), # e.g. John@john.com
  Field('tel'),   # e.g. 111 222 111
  ...)

db.define_table('letter',
  Field('sender', db.sender.id),     # e.g. Daniel
  Field('receiver', db.receiver.id), # e.g. John
  Field('opening'), # should be filled automatically when choosing/changing the value of "sender"
  ...)
```

so `letter.opening` should get the value of `receiver.opening[letter.sender.id]`, that means the value of `opening` of the chosen `sender`

Comment: Is there a reason you need the 'opening' field in the 'letter' table if it is simply a copy of the value of 'opening' from the 'sender' table? Are you unable to do joins (e.g., on GAE)?

Comment: yeah i want to make the user free to use the set value in `receiver` or to redefine it when writing the letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 'opening' text should be filled in instantly when the user selects a recipient, then you'll probably want to use Ajax. Check out this [lazy options widget](http://dev.s-cubism.com/plugin_lazy_options_widget). You'll have to modify it to fill in a string input instead of an options list, but otherwise it should do what you want.